# How to ask user to review the app in a flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I trying to ask the user to review the app, I looked into some packages and only found the rate_my_app, it has conditions like install time, number of launches, exactly what I need.
But I tested the package and is not working, I saw some recently issues been opened about problems with the package.
The other packages that I saw only launch a dialog to ask the app review and send it to the stores.
What are you guys using to ask the user to review the app?

Comment: Have you tried : https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_review

Comment: I saw it, but I didn't understand the package description saying `Beware that this does not guarantee that the pop up will be displayed as the quota may have been exceeded. On IOS & MacOS, this quota is three times in a 365 day period. On Android it is unclear:` there's a quota on iOS that limits the times I can ask the user to review my app?

Comment: @RafaelHonda exactly